# Tradução em sinônimos sugeridos

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

A tradução da dica que aparece quando passa o cursor por cima da pontuação de um sinônimo diz:

> total de votos (quando um sinônimo obtém uma pontuação de **-4**, ele é automaticamente aprovado)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra consertar basta tirar o sinal de negativo.

[Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bizarramente, as strings de aprovação e rejeição do sinônimos se misturaram e o sinal de - passou pro lado da aprovação também.

Novas versões:

- total de votos (um sinônimo é automaticamente aprovado ao atingir $PontuacaoParaAprovar$ pontos)
- total de votos (um sinônimo é automaticamente recusado ao atingir -$PontuacaoParaReprovar$ pontos)